# releasing object results in exc_bad_access

Tags: exc-bad-access

I am confused a little by the following code.  I was being a good soldier and dotting the i's and crossing the t's by releasing the tmp object in the following fragment.  However, at run time, i get "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

```
    -(void) aMethod {
            .
            .
        if (testMode) {         
            MyClass *tmp = [[MyClass alloc] init];
            [tmp aMethodInTheClass];
            [tmp release];
        }
            .
            .
    }
```

If I remove the [tmp release] statement, the error is not generated.

Is the release not needed because the scope of the 'tmp' object ceases after the inner if condition?

Thx.

Comment: Seems like your applecation needs a pointer to it! Define that variable in .h instantiae it in ur method and release it inside application dealloc method

Comment: But I did not want to introduce an instance variable for this temporary variable.

Comment: Check my answer that might work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
-(void) aMethod {
            .
            .
        if (testMode) {         
            MyClass *tmp = [[MyClass alloc] autorelease];
            [tmp aMethodInTheClass];
        }
            .
            .
    }
```

Good luck!